# google chrome extension http request monitoring for tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am working on google chrome extension application. I want, as soon as user's http request on browser's tab finished it give some alert. Means as browser finishes its request app could be able to listen it.

Right now i am using below code. It reads tab url after request finished.

```
chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener(function() {
    var mydiv = document.createElement('div');  
        chrome.tabs.getSelected(null,function(tab) {
        mydiv.innerHTML = tab.url;      
    });         
    document.body.appendChild(mydiv);
});
```

But it's not working for me. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably running the code from your background page (or else the **chrome.webRequest API** won't be available. From there (background page) it is not possible to interact with a webpages DOM.

You can achieve what you want like this:

**Solution A**

1. Have a **[content script](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html)** injected into the webpage at **["document_end" or "document_idle"](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#run_at)**.
2. The content script (once injected) will create your `div` and add it to the DOM.

**Solution B**

1. Have your background page listen for page load. BTW, **[chrome.tabs.onUpdated](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#event-onUpdated)** might be better suited for the task. E.g.:

   ```
   chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, info, tab) {  
       if (info.status && (info.status == "complete")) {
           // The page is loaded, so inject a content script
       }
   });
   ```
2. Upon page load **[programmatically inject](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#pi)** a content script.
3. The content script (once injected) will create your `div` and add it to the DOM.

Comment: Thanks. This is working great. But still I am facing problem with communication between popup.js and background.js. Any idea?

Comment: I'm glad it worked. I have lots of ideas, but if I don't see any code, I can't tell which one applies to your problem :) I suggest you post a new question, describing exactly what the problem is (and showing the code you've been using - the relevant parts only).